# Efficiency of & 1 over % 2

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Which one is the more efficient way to check whether the number is even? Given that `num` is an int.

```cs
if(num % 2 == 0)
// Or
if((num & 1) == 0)
```

Comment: Careful: you probably mean `(num & 1) == 0`. Lots of duplicates for this one, and the answer depends on the type of `num` and the language

Comment: Thank you for making me notice that!

Comment: C# works similar to C in this regard, and [here are some actual results](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIGYACMhgYQYG8aHunHgIIAGwYBLXDABuMAHYAKAK4jpGBggCUHLj23EA7KoYBSBqQYBeMwwAMAbi3cAvvYbP6DfkNHip00rKUq6prU2jr6CEYm5pa2zk4hPK58AsJikjJ0/sqqGpwJoUz6shEAZAzkGhbWdvkM8Q5AA===), look at the types.

Comment: @Nekuś the `%` is slower than `&`.

Comment: Thank you @harold! This link is of great help.

Comment: This is dependent of, how you define the `num`. If it is unsigned - for the `%`, compiler will just use mask, i.e. performance will be as same as with using `&`. However, if `num` is defined as `int`, i.e. signed int - then compiler will use several assembly commands, to prepare sign of result. Bevause of "-5 % 2 == -1". (my info - for gcc compiler, for C# result can be other).